# C++ Getting from A to Z from Virtual Keys

Tags: c++

More simpler code than this one?

According to Microsoft [website](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375731(v=vs.85).aspx), there are some constant that just increment the number(eg 0x41 is a, next to it is b which is 0x42) but some are not(eg 0x49 is I but next to it is 0x4A which is J).

How can I simplify this code using that pattern? Of course I wouldn't want to write all of those characters from A-Z.

```
bool CharIsPressed(int getKey)
{
    switch (getKey)
    {
    case 0x41:
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
            WriteKey("A");
        else
            WriteKey("a");
        break;
    case 0x42:
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
            WriteKey("B");
        else
            WriteKey("b");
        break;
    case 0x43:
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
            WriteKey("C");
        else
            WriteKey("c");
        break;
    case 0x44:
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
            WriteKey("D");
        else
            WriteKey("d");
        break;
    case 0x45:
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT))
            WriteKey("E");
        else
            WriteKey("e");
        break;
    default: return FALSE;
    }
}
```

Note: `WriteKey()` function is asking for `LPCSTR`, not `string`

Note: `getkey` is from `char key;` which returns ASCII codes

Comment: Why not use a static `std::map` that maps the virtual key to a letter? And if the shift-key is pressed use `std::toupper` on the character when you print it.

Comment: Check if the character is a letter, then if shift is pressed, uppercase it. No need for any `switch` hell. If the character is not a letter, return false.

Comment: still new to c++. also, need it because I need user input like SHIFT, ENTER etc.

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs C++ makes it so hard to uppercase/lowercase LPCSTR

Comment: Really? One function is hard? 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms647474(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Since this is Windows, you can pretty safely assume `'A'` through `'Z'` occupies 0x41 through 0x5A. I'm not sure what you mean by your note from the link in the question. Are you saying 0x49 + 1 is not 0x4A?

Comment: @LeśnyRumcajs sorry lol. Being a beginner to a such big language is really hard. Those examples like the one you gave me makes me confused

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan, For what it's worth, starting out programming by using the Windows API is one of the worst things you can do if your goal is to learn (good) C++. If you have a good handle on C or C++, then it's a lot easier to get into the Windows API, but it's still not the easiest API to use for sure.

Comment: @chris because c++ is my temporary platform because c# is harder to make a keylogger ;)

Comment: Sigh - what a novelty, yet another script kiddie using `GetAsyncKeyState` to make a keylogger. No bonus points awarded for originality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The virtual key codes for letters are the same as the ASCII codes of the uppercase letters. I don't get what you mean with the I/J example, 0x4a = 0x49 + 1.

Your code can be simplified like this

```
bool CharIsPressed(int getKey)
{
    char buf[2]=" ";
    if('A'<=getKey && getKey<='Z') {
        if(GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) buf[0]=getKey;
        else buf[0]=getKey+('a'-'A');
        WriteKey(buf);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Incidentally, your original code missed the `return` when it matched letters (which is undefined behavior), and returned `FALSE` instead of `false` in the other branch (the final result is the same, but conventionally `FALSE` is used for the Win32 `BOOL` type, while `false` is a "real" C++ `bool` literal).

Comment: `KHaIROUL` This is what I get after typing `Khairoul` on screen.

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan: where do `getKey` come from? Because if it comes from a `WM_KEYDOWN` or similar it's wrong to use `GetAsyncKeyState` (actually, it's almost never correct to use `GetAsyncKeyState`, since it's not synchronized with the input queues).

Comment: forgot to say, `getKey` is from `char key;` which returns ASCII code

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan: also, you are also using `GetAsyncKeyState` in a wrong way (and shame on me because I didn't notice during my copy/paste); `GetAsyncKeyState` returns a `SHORT` having the most significant bit set if the key is currently pressed and the least significant bit set if it was pressed since the last call to `GetAsyncKeyState`; thus, you have to check explicitly against a mask with the MSB set (see the updated example).

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan: the fact that it comes from some variable says nothing of where it actually comes from. How is that variable initialized? Is this function called in a `WM_KEYDOWN` and `key` comes from `wParam`? Or is it coming from `GetAsyncKeyState`?

Comment: @KhairoulIkhwan: that's not how you process input. `GetAsyncKeyState` bypasses the window input queues, thus not giving you a coherent view of the input events; usually there's no good reason to use it in a "normal" program. Learn how to process input properly in Win32 before making a mess with this stuff.

Comment: this works, but those !@#$%^&*() won't work because i need to code it manually

Comment: The general solution is to use the [ToAscii](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API (actually, the [ToUnicode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms646320%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) would be better as it handles even characters outside the current locale, but that requires some knowledge about wide characters).

Answer (score -1):

The integer value `int getKey` that you get in your function is actually the hex value of the character in ASCII format.

[ASCII Table](https://www.uni-due.de/hummell/infos/ascii/)

So you see that the Keycodes equal the value of the ASCII table for the capital letters (if shift is pressed). If shift is not pressed than you can add a offset of 0x20 to the Keycode to get the equvalent lowercase letter in ASCII Code.

So since the value for the letters is the same I would assume, that you can convert your KeyCode easily into a character with something like the following:

```
bool CharIsPressed(int getKey)
{
    char letter = getKey;
    char my_lpcstr[2] = {'x', '\0'};

    // Check if the input is no letter
    if((getKey < 'A') || (getKey > 'Z'))
        return false;

    if(!GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SHIFT)){
        letter += 0x20;
    }
    // Do a LPCSTR out of the char
    my_lpcstr[0] = letter;
    WriteKey(my_lpcstr);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: The function lacks `return`, for no reason set `my_lpcstr` to `x`, has redundant variable `letter` and doesn't even check if the incoming char is a lowercase letter. In fact, have you even read the function name?

Comment: I do noticed about this code and I've edited it. not so neat

Comment: `x` is just a random value, doesn't matter what and I know `letter` is redundant but I used it for better understanding the code and the main question was how to simplify the code, so you are right I didn't care about the return, but now I made an edit. Thanks.